# count function on json file not returning correct value (php)

Tags: php, json, count

I have a JSON file which contains reviews that I want to access. it looks like this:

```
{
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "Antrim Road",
            "short_name" : "Antrim Rd",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Belfast",
            "short_name" : "Belfast",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Newtownabbey",
            "short_name" : "Newtownabbey",
            "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Belfast",
            "short_name" : "Belfast",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Northern Ireland",
            "short_name" : "Northern Ireland",
            "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "United Kingdom",
            "short_name" : "GB",
            "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "BT36 7PN",
            "short_name" : "BT36 7PN",
            "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
         }
      ],
      "adr_address" : "\u003cspan class=\"street-address\"\u003eAntrim Road\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"extended-address\"\u003eBelfast\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"locality\"\u003eNewtownabbey\u003c/span\u003e \u003cspan class=\"postal-code\"\u003eBT36 7PN\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan class=\"country-name\"\u003eUK\u003c/span\u003e",
      "business_status" : "OPERATIONAL",
      "formatted_address" : "Antrim Rd, Belfast, Newtownabbey BT36 7PN, UK",
      "formatted_phone_number" : "028 9077 6277",
      "geometry" : {
         "location" : {
            "lat" : 54.6577821,
            "lng" : -5.943665699999999
         },
         "viewport" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 54.65913108029149,
               "lng" : -5.942316719708497
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 54.6564331197085,
               "lng" : -5.945014680291502
            }
         }
      },
      "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/generic_business-71.png",
      "international_phone_number" : "+44 28 9077 6277",
      "name" : "Belfast Zoo",
      "photos" : [
         {
            "height" : 1243,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/111863060002111236588\"\u003eBelfast Zoo\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJTIiPI3VznHujO9vTlzCagiH0Ak6dcoeZZsuNi8aIR1HzkLKmDbAEq-8ctO68YLbIuAqJeiu9X1tyhC6mKjcns0wGPRtTDqbhFTyle7LPE2oRa5Oda2FXzSDf8nrC1WR44YkdyPUhZUnN431HztHIFkbJF_eEYGvQffmflID9TqALU",
            "width" : 1776
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100936618118839321951\"\u003eAmanda Lewis\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwI55L16mowjExP5cOFV2wKThreGKXYT_1t6jK4JkGcUap94VNPF9dN2OniYKmi9YGDNqALwY4-6MWZoxm6-zyDNxog8g7c8UwD9UpXVrivmkfCpuY9MguXFiJlRVw9noyV6QMI-TO2bEVbvd7wQgnXn1Eaig_puaCDcylTcZ8nrOJAp",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116390912159770135890\"\u003eBeti Na\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJQ94yxuoAhN3MTMbf7DOdTgpJAYUoWbHFQW_i_uh6eQqdSdWzAiy5Du48Lm3bDnpWSPI4daH3AHem_XweVtP4MSaIPQZe4ozYWbEX1RPrKtDRMGu3kmqsMSCS84kyMLTlDOYpGuC7w4gqEzaqcg5DbIXiPoIAjXzFxTPCV1OdeRm8Q",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 9248,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/106644795451552578979\"\u003eMatthew mcmullan\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJDE3wE13EJptVWwrlPe_-n9HnwqU8Hs5y7HpWm_5hqMXvmo3AaZzyZsoZTfyV1M69dFgZnsJrP9iyiarwEuXYHPOA4ogvr0j-pn5XPk4nBdVrnPtbgPh0JYoym62ac3y1I33XBvwc-1eXk_MJbQJ_UvIcr2c6OmDLZSq0r4ESN6y7J",
            "width" : 6936
         },
         {
            "height" : 2988,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116390912159770135890\"\u003eBeti Na\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJbAFdJSWGNrd6uJb6yf_oM4Rfn2fkbewqz2lHTWl0buXcQ78YbBiJ8Ta_umMEo3XrFOS599cO-x01OvS83tiiIdlRXu8NOWcLxSpZmYuq41kG2KVyWz1MOJ9YjqZbLdIzADlZ641EipOAcmmZv-TBdbzHwHC7S3wrYrdaa67p7rvTR",
            "width" : 5312
         },
         {
            "height" : 3823,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/116284097622909280304\"\u003eBrian Cunningham\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwL7Z-RSxZ6pZ-i4XmKKgGNCazKNVw2bITY5sN1FFlDpbF01rF21rlpi54WJCHf23se8yAertLRQb-kAq2PLYB9ymsiQnrveFL-GttZjyGNwvuXpos-g9Lm0J58_I32Mr6YcgS5wfJIp74DQv2PyE6Wjo8NUrVyj5sLctb1FpVS92PuJ",
            "width" : 5735
         },
         {
            "height" : 4000,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/109005734355336105418\"\u003eWilliam Young\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwKPd5mh06H7KLngtPKQPfU8Wfq2BD08-iL51gJqhZea1zrZAK-eT6fAM3X8qde9TkciaMCgYo64_Ik1MEIIBAzDBYOt_2ug0pkeg3BWM7TNKyFu6k__qcImA2CFJE1AMsiKitlonSApY4w1t53D75rO0xEpmmL8cMRSIEt7YNrGhVSb",
            "width" : 2723
         },
         {
            "height" : 3024,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100719597211687837516\"\u003eJonathan Kelly\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwJCyTy5R0N7jNCmnggCXgn70Xgnws1KBXocRpAfjKBjEVZszRMQpQ9-ZZxZcPdaWzDKDtUhnEHyavQio3u3etvoc5q6RFaLGhOA7SK58wE84pbMEz5YazqArwuEA0jDBNEctRMO9J9DTYDhkt4jfrbTAke1-AfJTZFkukLwXjpA_oEA",
            "width" : 4032
         },
         {
            "height" : 3024,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104554106193648036788\"\u003eAjay Jose\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwKrV-cN2oWcr0iD65VKbfYTQLy1vLDPVs2YnbEtFq3Ne5KH16ooiWCD18Nc6VjZZ1Jr5Lt54yQtbRN7XIr-78e6YwtXrV1ue_0aHahqpv17YfscGFzfQ7X5SW0gEU19dbVSX0oC3BGdzAbHmjO04OXNS2vu6u1HDKT67mWlRTkSYovM",
            "width" : 4032
         },
         {
            "height" : 3024,
            "html_attributions" : [
               "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100719597211687837516\"\u003eJonathan Kelly\u003c/a\u003e"
            ],
            "photo_reference" : "ATtYBwKgM41e8PE5cKx_nAgU_fW4XHJeIy-StMar51N7ZbVjByUpfiqS7FbtQ-gWkGrRt9vNqOcsb9BysvgErNi-Ai0TEcQ2pLv5qOuyQ1S2uBWTWEksuV6wzDcXYNKTLa7uE-_H_rBH2pKoKCWl0meTtuq55HuNuFOkN6OEQESk-DN4ZzQH",
            "width" : 4032
         }
      ],
      "place_id" : "ChIJ88iCe5inYUgRdeXmfCtuvu4",
      "plus_code" : {
         "compound_code" : "M354+4G Belfast, UK",
         "global_code" : "9C6PM354+4G"
      },
      "rating" : 4.3,
      "reference" : "ChIJ88iCe5inYUgRdeXmfCtuvu4",
      "reviews" : [
         {
            "author_name" : "Karen Hoad",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/103129952317107981705/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-OkGM8wAyHz8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucn55YdMQZ1BX6ods-S34cieMQODrg/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba5/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 4,
            "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
            "text" : "Great place just not good when raining as the animals stay in",
            "time" : 1599236033
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "John Lee Ashworth",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/116452096322094109908/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-_ZpK7cdK1NI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuuclmcdFSQNilc5MfhJ3m8rRqzAXO_A/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 3,
            "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
            "text" : "Love zoos, love animals, hate nothing but steep hills though",
            "time" : 1598880406
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Clare",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/116989491220973031798/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GjK9VEovk8XRG41K9vVtu0SKRIHQdXp6Gb79opr_g=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba2",
            "rating" : 2,
            "relative_time_description" : "5 months ago",
            "text" : "Very little animals to see.",
            "time" : 1600628749
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Tammy 102",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/111672456708879530776/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-ngjoEXxeE8Q/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/AMZuucnTOkOTeq8ecWLEVbSs7UBnsUPmSQ/s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo-ba3/photo.jpg",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
            "text" : "To check prices",
            "time" : 1600610117
         },
         {
            "author_name" : "Mark Woonton",
            "author_url" : "https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/106800516570033737478/reviews",
            "language" : "en",
            "profile_photo_url" : "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GgnYZybrP-MTC4U45agdIlXMIFDIuH1v6roRuJAWQ=s128-c0x00000000-cc-rp-mo",
            "rating" : 5,
            "relative_time_description" : "6 months ago",
            "text" : "Amazing zoo, so much to see, a great day out",
            "time" : 1599993064
         }
      ],
      "types" : [ "zoo", "tourist_attraction", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=17203308759660029301",
      "user_ratings_total" : 2714,
      "utc_offset" : 0,
      "vicinity" : "Antrim Road, Belfast",
      "website" : "http://www.belfastzoo.co.uk/"
   },
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

it continues, but I want to loop through the number of reviews there are, so I can grab all of them and post it onto my website.

I am getting the count like this :

```
$json = json_decode($place_id, true);
$reviewCount = count($json);
```

and then I have my for loop:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $reviewCount; $i++){
...
}
```

What I've realised is my count always returns 3. I used var_dump to see what it actually counts, and its not the reviews.

I'm not sure how I would actually count the number of reviews, so I'm stuck as this point.

Any help or even info would be massively appriciated, thanks!

(edited to provide the entire json file)

Comment: Surely you want `count($json['reviews']);`

Comment: It might be because the decoded `json` object has only 3 *keys* namely, `rating`, `reference` and `reviews` ... so it's length _is_ 3. You need to count the length of the `reviews` bit. Something like `count($json->reviews)`

Comment: Aside: in the code shown here, you're assigning the count to `reviewCount` (which needs a `$` in front as it's a PHP var) but in the loop you're comparing to `$elementCount` ... I'm assuming that's just an error in what you've put into the question, rather than a bug in the actual code?

Comment: yes thats just an error in the question but good spot!

Comment: I tried the method given by NigelRen and @CD001 but I get this error: 
"Warning: Attempt to read property "reviews" on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\cw\tester.php on line 75"

Comment: See the comment by @NigelRen then ;) If the decoded JSON is an array rather than an object then `$json['reviews']` would be the correct way to access that element.

Comment: `$json = json_decode($place_id, true);` ... having `true` as the 2nd parameter means it _should_ be an associative array (so you'd use `$json['reviews']`) - and the fact that you had a count of `3` on `count($json)` implies that the json *was* decoded successfully... what do you get if you `var_dump($json)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, seeing that you updated your question, you will need to count your reviews like this:

```
$objFromJson = json_decode($jsonString, true);
$reviews=$objFromJson["result"]["reviews"];
$reviewCount = count($reviews); // 5

echo "The count is $reviewCount, here are the individual reviews:\n\n";
foreach ($reviews as $rev) echo $rev["author_name"].": ".$rev["text"]."\n";
```

I also changed your `for` loop into a `foreach` loop, see  my (updated) demo here: https://rextester.com/JQEU23562

output:

```
The count is 5, here are the individual reviews:

Karen Hoad: Great place just not good when raining as the animals stay in
John Lee Ashworth: Love zoos, love animals, hate nothing but steep hills though
Clare: Very little animals to see.
Tammy 102: To check prices
Mark Woonton: Amazing zoo, so much to see, a great day out
```

Comment: The issue is it returns this: 
"Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($var) must be of type Countable|array, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\cw\tester.php:44 Stack trace: #0 {main}"

Comment: It *does* work in the rextester snippet. Maybe there is something else not properly set up in your PHP file itself?

Comment: Okay so I think I understand what is wrong and its a schoolboy error from me.. I will update the question, but I will give the entire JSON file, 'reviews' is inside object 'result', if you could help me with the full JSON that would be amazing!